# Clang missing frameworks with Qt 6 on Mac ARM

Tags: macos, c++17, qt6, apple-silicon

I'm trying to build a C++ Qt project for Mac ARM using Qt 6.5.3 in QtCreator and getting the following 2 errors when I build:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices'
```

I have Xcode 13.4.1 installed on MacOS 12.5.1, which should be a supported configuration according to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/macos.html).
My .pro file has:

```
QMAKE_APPLE_DEVICE_ARCHS = arm64
```

I have tried selecting different clang compilers (/usr/bin/clang++ and the Xcode compiler path given by 'xcrun -sdk macosx -find clang'). Both produce the same error.
I also tried adding:

```
LIBS += -framework CoreFoundation
```

But that didn't help, either.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using an old version of crashpad that was explicitly adding in those old libs in the .pri file.